# macOS: How to detect if dark mode is active in Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal, macos-mojave, delphi

What is, in macOS Mojave and with Lazarus / Free Pascal, the recommended way to detect if the dark mode has been activated?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=43111.0 ?

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising, but still seems to be a somewhat unfinished technique.

Comment: I tested it, and it seems to be a fairly good solution.

Comment: In that case I suggest you write it up as an answer to your q.

Comment: This is a good idea, but there is still an ongoing discussion at http://forum.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?topic=43111.0 . I would like to wait until it settles at an agreement of best practice.